# Python: Failed in retrieving the highest amount from a repeated data with different amount in a certain year

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv, ordereddictionary

The csv file that I have contain several repeated supplier_name but with different amt for year 2015-2017.

Here goes my codes.

```
df = pd.read_csv('government-procurement-via-gebiz.csv', parse_dates=['award_date'], 
infer_datetime_format=True, usecols=['supplier_name', 'award_date', 'awarded_amt'],)
df = df[(df['supplier_name'] != 'na') & (df['award_date'].dt.year == 2015)].reset_index(drop=True)

d1 = df.set_index('supplier_name').to_dict()['awarded_amt']
top5D1 = dict(sorted(d1.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:5])

print top5D1
```

The output is

```
{'KAJIMA OVERSEAS ASIA PTE LTD': 595800000.0, 'SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION': 555322063.0, 'GS Engineering & Construction Corp.': 428301000.0, 'HYUNDAI ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION CO. LTD': 601726000.0, 'THE GO-AHEAD GROUP PLC': 497738104.0}
```

I check on the csv file, the correct result should be this.

```
                                supplier_name award_date   awarded_amt
1             SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD. 2015-01-07  1.030000e+09
2  HYUNDAI ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION CO. LTD 2015-08-04  6.017260e+08
3                KAJIMA OVERSEAS ASIA PTE LTD 2015-02-03  5.958000e+08
4                     SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION 2015-11-20  5.553221e+08
5                      THE GO-AHEAD GROUP PLC 2015-11-23  4.977381e+08
```

From the csv file I found that " SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD. " supplier_name appeared twice on the csv file one is the lowest and the others is the highest amt.

How am I suppose to output I " SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD. " highest amt out?

The csv data is something like this.

```
1/7/2015    SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.                 1030000000
8/4/2015    HYUNDAI ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION CO. LTD      601726000
2/3/2015    KAJIMA OVERSEAS ASIA PTE LTD                    595800000
11/20/2015  SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION                         555322063
11/23/2015  THE GO-AHEAD GROUP PLC                          497738104
6/19/2015   GS Engineering & Construction Corp.             428301000
6/25/2015   TIONG SENG CONTRACTORS (PRIVATE) LIMITED        277265946
2/27/2015   CHIP ENG SENG CONTRACTORS (1988) PTE LTD        258000000
11/18/2015  TEAMBUILD ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.  236800000
2/23/2015   NCS PTE. LTD.                                   223028240
11/11/2015  HSL Constructor Pte Ltd                         217354000
7/31/2015   HI-TEK CONSTRUCTION PTE LTD                     215000000
6/22/2015   HWA SENG BUILDER PTE LTD                        189339600
3/19/2015   EXPAND CONSTRUCTION PTE LTD                     189000000
11/30/2015  CNQC ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.       163980000
9/7/2015    Master Contract Services Pte Ltd                163000000
3/5/2015    Yongnam Engineering & Construction Pte Ltd      159000000
5/19/2015   SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.                 148800000
```

Comment: Can you also include, as text, the pertinent data lines form the CSV, so we can recreate the problem?

Comment: Hi, sorry i do not really understand what you mean? The CSV file contain 18544 records with several columns from the year 2015 to 2017.@RightmireM

Comment: Sure. Well, two options. 1) You think that the reason the issue is happening is because " SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD. " appears twice. So give us - say - 20 lines from the CSV INCLUDING the two lines with " SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD. ". 2) Post the actual CSV somewhere on the web (if it does NOT contain proprietary or other private data) so we can parse the list and recreate your issue.  But we need some original input data to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Can yo add that into the body of the original question, formatted please?

Comment: ok sure, I have updated it @RightmireM

Answer (score 0):

The problem is; when you create the dictionary with `to_dict` it creates the desired first instance of "SANTARLI" as a key, and then as it continues to parse, it finds the second instance of "SANTARLI", which it uses as a key, replacing the first instance's key (overwriting the key and data.)

Dictionary keys must be unique. You need to clean your data of redundant instances first. See below...

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import operator

#df = pd.read_csv('government-procurement-via-gebiz.csv', parse_dates=['award_date'], infer_datetime_format=True, usecols=['supplier_name', 'award_date', 'awarded_amt'],)
# I creatd the df from the data supplied in the questions
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['award_date', 'supplier_name', 'awarded_amt'])
df['award_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['award_date'])
print(df)

# Select by date (your original code)
df = df[(df['supplier_name'] != 'na') & (df['award_date'].dt.year == 2015)].reset_index(drop=True)

# Sort by column 'awarded_amt'. 
# This will leave the duplicates like 'SANTARLI', but put the one with the highest 
#  value in 'awarded_amt' first
df = df.sort_values('awarded_amt', ascending=True)

# Drop the duplicates. This has a parameter "keep" which defaults to "first"
# Thus, it will keep the first instance of 'SANTARLI', 
#  which will also be the greatest 'awarded_amt'
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['supplier_name'])

# Now create your dict
d1 = df.set_index('supplier_name').to_dict()['awarded_amt']
print(d1)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
award_date                                      supplier_name awarded_amt
0 2015-01-07                    SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.  1030000000
1 2014-08-04         HYUNDAI ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION CO. LTD   601726000
2 2014-02-03                       KAJIMA OVERSEAS ASIA PTE LTD   595800000
3 2015-11-20                            SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION   555322063
4 2015-11-23                             THE GO-AHEAD GROUP PLC   497738104
5 2015-06-19                GS Engineering & Construction Corp.   428301000
6 2015-09-07                   Master Contract Services Pte Ltd   163000000
7 2015-03-05         Yongnam Engineering & Construction Pte Ltd   159000000
8 2015-12-30  NANJING DADI CONSTRUCTION (GROUP) CO., LTD. SI...   152600000
9 2015-05-19                    SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.   148800000

{'SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.': '1030000000', 'NANJING DADI CONSTRUCTION (GROUP) CO., LTD. SINGAPORE BRANCH': '152600000', 'Yongnam Engineering & Construction Pte Ltd': '159000000', 'Master Contract Services Pte Ltd': '163000000', 'GS Engineering & Construction Corp.': '428301000', 'THE GO-AHEAD GROUP PLC': '497738104', 'SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION': '555322063'}
```

**EDIT:**
If you just want the top 5 rows based on "awarded_amt" for each year (I.e. The top 5 "awarded_amt"s regardless of whether those are 5 different companies, or the same companies) then don't do a drop duplicates at all.

Just sort the entire DataFrame by "awarded_amt", take the top 5 (maybe use df.head(5) ), but DON'T use the to_dict() (using the company names as keys) since it won't allow two (or more) of the same company names.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

data = [["1/7/2015", "SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.", 1030000000],
["8/4/2015", "HYUNDAI ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION CO. LTD", 601726000], 
["2/3/2015", "KAJIMA OVERSEAS ASIA PTE LTD", 595800000], 
["11/20/2015","SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION",                         555322063],
["11/23/2015" ,"THE GO-AHEAD GROUP PLC",                          497738104],
["6/19/2015"   ,"GS Engineering & Construction Corp.",             428301000],
["6/25/2015"   ,"TIONG SENG CONTRACTORS (PRIVATE) LIMITED",        277265946],
["5/19/2015"   ,"SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD."          ,       649800000],
["5/19/2016"   ,"SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD."          ,       650800000],
["5/19/2016"   ,"SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD."          ,       651800000],
["11/20/2016","SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION",                         555322063],
["11/23/2016" ,"THE GO-AHEAD GROUP PLC",                          497738104],
["6/19/2016"   ,"GS Engineering & Construction Corp.",             428301000]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['award_date', 'supplier_name', 'awarded_amt'])
df['award_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['award_date'])
# Separate df by years
finaldf = pd.DataFrame()
years = [2015, 2016]
for year in years:
    temp_df = df[(df['supplier_name'] != 'na') & (df['award_date'].dt.year == year)].reset_index(drop=True)
#     Sort by column 'awarded_amt'. 
#     This will leave the duplicates like 'SANTARLI', but put the one with the highest 
#      value in 'awarded_amt' first
    temp_df = temp_df.sort_values('awarded_amt', ascending=False)
    print("-----------------------____")
    finaldf = pd.concat([finaldf, temp_df.iloc[:5]]) 
print(finaldf)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
award_date                               supplier_name  awarded_amt
0 2015-01-07             SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.   1030000000
7 2015-05-19             SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.    649800000
1 2015-08-04  HYUNDAI ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION CO. LTD    601726000
2 2015-02-03                KAJIMA OVERSEAS ASIA PTE LTD    595800000
3 2015-11-20                     SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION    555322063
1 2016-05-19             SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.    651800000
0 2016-05-19             SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.    650800000
2 2016-11-20                     SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION    555322063
3 2016-11-23                      THE GO-AHEAD GROUP PLC    497738104
4 2016-06-19         GS Engineering & Construction Corp.    428301000
```

**EDIT:**

To transform `finaldf` to a dictionary, I would recommend this. It will create a nested dictionary, similar to JSON. You could also use the Python module `JSON` for this.

```
final_dict = {}
for row in finaldf.iterrows():
    award_date    = row[1][0]
    supplier_name = row[1][1]
    awarded_amt   = row[1][2]
    if supplier_name not in final_dict.keys():
        final_dict[supplier_name] = {}
    final_dict[supplier_name][award_date] = awarded_amt

print(final_dict)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
  'SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.': {
    Timestamp('2015-01-07 00:00:00'): 1030000000, 
    Timestamp('2015-05-19 00:00:00'): 649800000, 
    Timestamp('2016-05-19 00:00:00'): 650800000
  }, 
  'HYUNDAI ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION CO. LTD': {
    Timestamp('2015-08-04 00:00:00'): 601726000
  }, 
  'KAJIMA OVERSEAS ASIA PTE LTD': {
    Timestamp('2015-02-03 00:00:00'): 595800000
  }, 
  'SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION': {
    Timestamp('2015-11-20 00:00:00'): 555322063, 
    Timestamp('2016-11-20 00:00:00'): 555322063
  }, 
  'THE GO-AHEAD GROUP PLC': {
    Timestamp('2016-11-23 00:00:00'): 497738104
  }, 
  'GS Engineering & Construction Corp.': {
    Timestamp('2016-06-19 00:00:00'): 428301000
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, am i suppose to follow the top part of the codes? because I start copied 
" df = df.sort_values('awarded_amt', ascending=True) " and " df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['supplier_name'])
# Now create your dict
d1 = df.set_index('supplier_name').to_dict()['awarded_amt'] " 

and I didnt get the result that is suppose to output

Comment: sorry it seems like the sorting of values is not working.

Comment: You'll notice in the first paragraph pf code, I commented out your line which loads the data from the file (since I don't have the file) and instead created the data from a list-of-lists generated form the original data text you put into the question. Since this text may not be identical to what you get out of the CSV file when you use `csv_load()` - you may need to tweak the code a bit. I would suggest looking through the code offered, and looking up each function to see how it works. That should give you the knowledge to implement it with the actual code.

Comment: The first part of the **OUTPUT:** secont is what the `df` looks like after I loaded the data. The code works with that. So, use it as a reference to get it working with what you get out of the `df.csv_load()`

Comment: ok sure, thanks I saw my top result with the SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD being included its just the sort by top 5 having some problem. because it is not being place in the first place.

Comment: Hi, sorry ist possible to have another way to not drop the duplicate but just to retrieve the highest value from the same supplier name in the same year?

Comment: Im not sure. Probably, but it seems an inefficient way to go about it. why do you want to do it another way?

Comment: From the excel, year 2016. The top 5 consist of 2 company that is of the same name but different value so when i drop duplicate it doesnt show the company of the same name twice on the top 5.

Comment: Well, I thought that was the goal; to only have the company appear name once, showing only the highest value for that company. If you only want the company to show once (with the highest value) for each year - then divide each year into separate DataFrames, get the single-company-with-highest-value for each, and merge them again. If you want companies to show up twice, each with their respective values, then you need to not use the `to_dict` - or at least don't use it with the company names as the keys. (...cont...)

Comment: A Python dictionary key must be unique and immutable. So, if you use `to_dict()` using the company names for the keys, if you have two company names that are identical (i.e. "SANTARLI" = 12345, and "SANTARLI" = 1234567) what happens is; python sets `{SANTARLI:12345}` on one iteration, and then tries to set `{SANTARLI:1234567}` on another iteration - and since it can't have 2 keys names `SANTARLI`, the first `{SANTARLI:12345}` is destroyed. Thats why you only end up with one.

Comment: If you just want the top 5 rows based on "awarded_amt" (I.e. The top 5 "awarded_amt"s regardless of whether those are 5 different companies, or the same companies) then don't do a drop duplicates at all. Just sort the entire DataFrame by "awarded_amt", take the top 5 (maybe use df.head(5) ), but DON'T use the `to_dict()` (using the company names as keys) since it won't allow two (or more) of the same company names.

Comment: I have posted my new codes. Can you please have a look for me ? sorry. 
@RightmireM

Comment: I added some new code to the above answer. See if that helps at all :)

Comment: for the edited version ist possible for it to be in dictionary form?
0 2015-01-07             SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.   1030000000
7 2015-05-19             SANTARLI CONSTRUCTION PTE. LTD.    649800000