# Python: Retrieve the highest value between a duplicate name and output the respective data from a csv file into a dictionary format

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, ordereddictionary

[Previous solution that I had gotten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58471634/python-failed-in-retrieving-the-highest-amount-from-a-repeated-data-with-differ/58473638?noredirect=1#comment103282401_58473638)

The following codes that I have improved on.

Passed from a csv file and retrieve the data . From years in 2015,2016,2017 respectively.

```
df = pd.read_csv('government-procurement-via-gebiz.csv', parse_dates=['award_date'], 
infer_datetime_format=True, usecols=['supplier_name', 'award_date', 'awarded_amt'],)

df = df[(df['supplier_name'] != 'na') & (df['award_date'].dt.year == 
2016)].reset_index(drop=True)

# df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['supplier_name'])
df = df.sort_values('awarded_amt', ascending=False).nlargest(5,'awarded_amt')
d1 = df.set_index('supplier_name')['awarded_amt']
print d1
```

The following is my output.

```
supplier_name                                   awarded_amt
GS ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION CORP.             1.988000e+09
SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION                         8.336120e+08
PENTA-OCEAN CONSTRUCTION CO LTD                 6.744177e+08
SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION                         4.509105e+08
KTC CIVIL ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION PTE LTD    4.175000e+08
```

How am i suppose to output them in dictionary format.

Comment: Nope, i tried. it doesnt work.
{'SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION': 450910504.0, 
'PENTA-OCEAN CONSTRUCTION CO LTD': 674417748.0, 
'KTC CIVIL ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION PTE LTD': 417500000.0, 
'GS ENGINEERING & CONSTRUCTION CORP.': 1988000000.0}

Comment: You can't. Dictionaries must have unique keys. You have two `'SAMSUNG C&T CORPORATION'` in your supplier name, you cannot make a dictionary using that column as keys. As you have seen, one of them is overwritten.

Comment: is there totally no way to keep it as dictionary format?

Comment: As it is, no. Dictionaries cannot have duplicated keys. You can of course find a workaround which is suitable for you. For example, appending a 1, 2, 3, etc. to the key in case of duplicated values in the column. It's up to you to choose if this workaround (or another one you may think to make the keys unique) is fine for your needs or not.